# Libvirt: ERROR No domains available for virt type 'hvm', arch 'x86_64', domain type 'kvm'

Tags: debian, kvm-virtualization, libvirt

Installed virt-man like this

```
$ apt-get install virt-manager
$ modprobe kvm
$ modprobe vhost-net
```

Launching libvirt guest

```
$ virt-install --virt-type kvm \
--name centos-6.5 --ram 1024 \
--cdrom=CentOS-6.5-x86_64-minimal.iso 
--disk centos-6.5.qcow2,format=qcow2 \ 
--network network=default \
--graphics vnc,listen=0.0.0.0 \
--noautoconsole --os-type=linux \ 
--os-variant=rhel6
```

And it throws an error:

```
ERROR    No domains available for virt type 'hvm', arch 'x86_64', domain type 'kvm'
```

Validate command shows that's everything should work.

```
$ virt-host-validate 
QEMU: Checking for hardware virtualization                                 : PASS
QEMU: Checking for device /dev/kvm                                         : PASS
QEMU: Checking for device /dev/vhost-net                                   : PASS
QEMU: Checking for device /dev/net/tun                                     : PASS
 LXC: Checking for Linux >= 2.6.26                                         : PASS
```

Standart solutions I've found are usually related to missing kernel modules like kvm_intel for example, but it's loaded, although with warning

```
$ dmesg | grep kvm
[   10.279733] kvm: VM_EXIT_LOAD_IA32_PERF_GLOBAL_CTRL does not work properly. Using workaround
```

Update: Here's more info:

```
$ cat /proc/cpustat
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 44
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           E5620  @ 2.40GHz
stepping    : 2
microcode   : 0x10
cpu MHz     : 1596.000
cache size  : 12288 KB
physical id : 1
siblings    : 8
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 4
apicid      : 32
initial apicid  : 32
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 11
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid dca sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt aes lahf_lm ida arat epb dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid
bogomips    : 4788.24
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 40 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

Comment: what do you mean what I'm trying to do? you don't know what `virt-install` does?

Comment: edited question, i don't know why people need explanation on bash commands in here.. but whatever if it's makes sense to you

Comment: are you able to install using virt-mnager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution found

Appears to be that `--connect qemu:///system` param should be added, one guy in irc proposed that this is due install of virtualbox in my machine.

Then I've been stuck with this error:

```
ERROR    Error in network device parameters: Virtual network 'default' has not been started.
```

I had to use `virt-manager` to actually start vm.. then it created default network automatically.

Comment: <<I had to use virt-manager to actually start vm.. then it created default network automatically.  RE>I think it is actually starting libvirtd service,you can do this manually /etc/init.d/libvirtd start.

Answer (score 4):

In my case the problem is with hardware virtualization disabled in BIOS. Also I was in a state that I can't turn that on. Replacing 'kvm' with 'qemu' fixed my problem.